# How to call WPF project app.xaml.cs file by just navigating to it's one of the page from another WPF application. Is this possible to call?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the two WPF applications "Application A" and Application B.
From "Application A" I am navigating to "ABC.xaml" page of "Application B". I want to call app.xaml.cs file of "Application B" before navigate to "ABC.xaml" page. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. app.xaml.cs *file* cannot be called. it is a file. it stores data, nothing more.

Comment: In Silverlight it is working, so i am wondering how it is possible there and not in WPF. Since both are from the same family. I am in the process of migrating the silverlight application to wpf application, so would like to know possible solution of above problem. In Silverlight Solution both "Application A" and  "Application B" are different project and app.xaml is doing beyond storing data, it is initializing the module, resolving dependencies and many more things.